# Самый производительный алгоритм сортировки

Tags: сортировка, любой-язык

У меня есть число в рамках `1<N<10^6` пусть это будет кол-во машин, а также есть цена каждой машины `0<p<100` числа могут повторяться, мне нужно все цены отсортировать, я подумал что нужно выбирать алгоритм сортировки в зависимости от значения N,

```
if(N > 100) => first sort alghoritm
if(N > 100000) => second sort alghoritm
if(N > 1000000) => third sort alghoritm
```

или не важно сколько чисел, стоит использовать один алгоритм сортировки?

Comment: что то каша какая то...3 языка ничем не связаны между собой выбраны у вас. У меня сразу вопрос...это вы на `js` или `c#` собираетесь сортировать 10000000 данных? цена чего у вас ? Если так много данных, то нужно смотреть в сторону БД.

Comment: языки добавлены для тегов, максимальное кол-во чисел это 10^6

Comment: Взять метод сортировки, который уже есть в стандартной библиотеке языка и ничего не выдумывать.

Comment: *числа могут повторяться* Реальные данные - именно безличные числа (в смысле - нужна ли устойчивость)? Обладает ли исходная последовательность регулярностью (частичная упорядоченность), или она полностью случайна? В общем - возможно ли изначально предсказать, что некий алгоритм из двух сравнимых на реально сортируемых данных более эффективен? Если да - то, возможно, набор алгоритмов в зависимости от объёма и может иметь смысл. Но это весьма нечастая ситуация.

Comment: На мой взгляд, миллион не так много, чтобы анализировать данные и выбирать наиболее оптимальный алгоритм.

Comment: в общем у меня есть массив byte[N] 1<N<10^6 и из этого массива мне нужно подставить числа в формулу x = 2 * byte[i]; где byte[i] начинается с самого большого числа, ну я подумал что для начала стоило бы отсортировать массив byte[N] по убыванию

Comment: ограничение по времени 5с, по памяти 246мб

Comment: @Akina, какая разница, ты на ограничения посмотри.

Comment: *у меня есть массив byte[N] 1<N<10^6* Ну вот... а ты - машины, цены... байты (особенно в таком количестве) следует однозначно сортировать подсчётом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `0<p<100`

Корзинная сортировка. Асимптотика O(N+p).

```
var b = new List<Car>[100];
for each (var c in cars) b[c.price].Add(c);
var res = b.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

> мне нужно все цены отсортировать

Так цены отсортировать или машины?

Если цены, то сортировка подсчётом, асимптотика та же.

```
var b = new int[100];

for each (var x in a)
  ++b[x];

for (var q=0, i=0; q<b.Length; ++q)
  for (var w=0; w<b[q]; ++w)
    a[i++] = q;
```